# SQL conditional constraint on multiple columns being unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to have a conditional constraint on my database:

[image]

You can see that my `CreatedBy` column has a few entries missing due to legacy data problems.

My new code ensures the `CreatedBy` is filled out.

**Question:**

I would like to ensure that noone can enter duplicate entries into the db by adding a conditional constraint. that defines that a row should be unique by `AnswerID`, `PollID` and `CreatedBy`... only if `CreatedBy` is not empty

It might look like this:

```
CONSTRAINT UNIQUE BY AnswerID, PollID, CreatedBy WHERE CreatedBy IS NOT NULL
```

Any ideas if it's possible?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Thanks, hope that helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, use a [filtered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes):

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX <indexName>
    ON <tableName> (AnswerID, PollID, CreatedBy)  
    WHERE CreatedBy IS NOT NULL;
```

Or, since you said "not empty" then something like this should do:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX <indexName>
    ON <tableName> (AnswerID, PollID, CreatedBy)  
    WHERE CreatedBy IS NOT NULL
      AND CreatedBy <> N'';
```

Comment: It's... it's beautiful (wipes tear from face). Thanks, i'm giving it a try now!

Answer (score 1):

If version is prior to 2008:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_Tablename
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT AnswerID, PollID, CreatedBy
FROM dbo.Tablename
WHERE CreatedBy IS NOT NULL;

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UIX_vw_Tablename 
  ON dbo.vw_Tablename(AnswerID, PollID, CreatedBy)
```